# Splitting a String with two criteria

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string as listed below.

> string sample = " class0 .calss1 .class2 .class3.class4  .class5 class6 .class7";

I need to create a list of WORDS from this sample string.

A WORD is a string that starts with a period and ends with:

1. a space or
2. another period or
3. end of string

**Note**: The key point here is - the splitting is based on two criteria - a period and a blank space

I have following program. It works fine. However, is there a simpler/more efficient/concise approach using `LINQ` or `Regular Expressions`?

CODE

```
        List<string> wordsCollection = new List<string>();
        string sample = " class0 .calss1 .class2 .class3.class4  .class5 class6 .class7";

        string word = null;

        int stringLength = sample.Length;
        int currentCount = 0;

        if (stringLength > 0)
        {
            foreach (Char c in sample)
            {

                currentCount++;
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
                {
                    if (c == '.')
                    {
                        word = Convert.ToString(c);
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    if (c == ' ')
                    {
                        //End Criteria Reached
                        word = word + Convert.ToString(c);
                        wordsCollection.Add(word);
                        word = String.Empty;
                    }
                    else if (c == '.')
                    {
                        //End Criteria Reached
                        wordsCollection.Add(word);
                        word = Convert.ToString(c);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        word = word + Convert.ToString(c);
                        if (stringLength == currentCount)
                        {
                            wordsCollection.Add(word);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

RESULT

```
        foreach (string wordItem in wordsCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(wordItem);

        }
```

[image]

Reference:

1. [Splitting up a string, based on predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265303/splitting-up-a-string-based-on-predicate)
2. [Is there a better way to get sub-sequences where each item matches a predicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568724/is-there-a-better-way-to-get-sub-sequences-where-each-item-matches-a-predicate?rq=1)
3. [Linq based generic alternate to Predicate<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783767/linq-based-generic-alternate-to-predicatet?rq=1)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b873y76a.aspx

Comment: Check out [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @VladL The splitting is based on two criteria - a period and a blank space. How can it be done with String.Split ?

Comment: @MarkByers I have updated the question with a screenshot of expected result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a regular expression.

**Code**

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\.[^ .]+");
var matches = regex.Matches(sample);
string[] result = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/kFPTG5)

**Result**

```
.calss1
.class2
.class3
.class4
.class5
.class7
```

**Explanation of Regular Expression**

```
\.      Match a dot
[^. ]+  Negative character class - anything apart from space or dot (at least one)
```

**Related**

- [Character Classes or Character Sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: +1 I usually frown on regular expressions for splitting strings, but this is a case where it's the best way to do it.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what you mean by "as few as possible"

Comment: @Lijo: Regular expressions are greedy by default. The `?` modifier makes the `*` [lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy).

Comment: Thanks for the reference too http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy. It would be great if you can update the answer with these details and link

Comment: @Lijo: Thought about it a bit and updated to a simpler regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

```
string sample = " class0 .calss1 .class2 .class3.class4  .class5 class6 .class7";

string[] words = sample.Split(new char[] {'.'}).Skip(1).Select(x=> 
            "." + x.Split(new char[] {' '})[0].Trim()).ToArray();
```

EDIT missed the list part:

```
List<string> words = sample.Split(new char[] {'.'}).Skip(1).Select(x=> 
            "." + x.Split(new char[] {' '})[0].Trim()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to keep the . and the space?

If not you can use:

```
sample.Split(new char[]{' ', '.'}).ToList();
```

This will give you a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
string sample = " class0 .calss1 .class2 .class3.class4 .class5 class6 .class7";
sample = Regex.Replace(sample, " ", String.Empty);
string[] arr = sample.Split(new char[] { '.' });
```

Comment: Don't you see class0 coming in the result?